# React - How to implement isLogin() function?

Tags: reactjs, api

I am working on implementing authentication in React. I have followed the guide https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e to implement Private and Public routes. Everything works fine.

To summarise my routes look like this:

```
    <PublicRoute restricted={true} component={Login} exact path="/login">
    <PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/dashboard" exact />
```

My private and public routes check if user is logged in through isLogin() function. I have implemented it in a following way:

```
 export const isLogin = () => {
     if(getToken('myToken') == true) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
```

getToken() is basically a function which retrieves token from local storage and returns true or false. Now my question is how do I verify if myToken is a valid token from API and then return true or false accordingly?

Comment: I actually just started working on JWT authentication in a MERN app, I'd recommend checking out the linked tutorial for setting up user authentication and public/private routes. It should answer your question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H15hpteBdL8&list=PLvTjg4siRgU0HS3cANo7KZ52Wkud083TL&ab_channel=NoobCoder

Answer (score 0):

For that you have two option
1). if you have refresh token API than call it when route is change or may be page get refresh if the token is expire than remove token from local storage and redirect user to login page.
2). Another one is you have to set expire time of token in local storage if time expire than logout the user also if you call the any API than validate token in backend if the token will expire the API gives 401 means unauthorized than you can logout the user.

```
export const isLogin = ({children:children}) => {
  if(getToken('myToken') === true) {  
      return children; 
   } 
   history.push('/login') 
};
```

Comment: can you provide any example for this? like the implementation of isLogin() in this case?

Comment: export const isLogin = ({children:children}) => {
     if(getToken('myToken') === true) {
         return children;
     }
history.push('/login')
     }
you may use it as isLogin function

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react-router new version (v6) than use  ohterwise use ,...
and in path if you have dynamic route list than use like  otherwise call all the component inside 
here is

```
const isLogin = localStorage.getItem('login');

function RequireAuth({children}) {
   return isLogin ? children : <Navigate to="/sign-in" replace/>;
}



<Routes>
    <Route path={'*'} element={<RequireAuth><RouteList/></RequireAuth>}/>
</Routes>
```